# unixODBC Driver Manager Can't open lib

Tags: sql-server, django, pyodbc, freetds, django-pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server db using django 1.10 and pyodbc, Mas Os X 10.11.5

Firstly, when I'm typing

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

the traceback is

```
('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'FreeTDS' file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

So I've installed

```
brew install freetds
```

so my /usr/local/lib/

contains

```
libct.4.dylib       libct.dylib     libodbc.dylib       libodbccr.dylib     libodbcinst.dylib   libsybdb.a
libct.a         libodbc.2.dylib     libodbccr.2.dylib   libodbcinst.2.dylib libsybdb.5.dylib    libsybdb.dylib
```

but error message is still the same

```
('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'FreeTDS' file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

The question is what should I write in odbcinst.ini? Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: does it still throw the error after installing the library?

Comment: i used this post to configure pyodbc http://www.tivix.com/blog/getting-django-working-with-mssql-pyodbc/

Comment: @ZagorodniyOlexiy Can you please answer the question with the solution? The link is broken.